# Why is it a bad idea to use scope resolution operator with a private method?

Tags: c++, function, class

Suppose I have some class

```
class ClassOne {
    private:
    void methodOne();

    public:
    void methodTwo();
};
```

Now

```
void ClassOne::methodOne() { // <-- private
   // other code
}

void ClassOne::methodTwo() { // <-- public
   // other code
   ClassOne::methodOne(); // <-- private function called with scope resolution operator
}
```

I have been told this is something that I shouldn't do and instead to

```
void ClassOne::methodTwo() { // <-- public
   // other code
   methodOne();              // <-- private function 
}
```

Can someone explain why this is not goot practice or wrong practice?

When I compile I get no errros, so I want to understand what issue can occur.

Comment: It's extra typing that probably doesn't convey much to a reader. You're inside the definition of a class member function, members of the class are already in scope and you don't need to qualify them. Sometimes it's necessary to do, if `methodOne` is virtual and you really want the `ClassOne` version of it and not some derived class's override. But that's pretty rare.

Comment: There are situations where adding a class qualifier changes the meaning of the code. If you write class qualifiers where they do not affect the meaning you make it harder for readers of your code (including your future self) to spot the ones that matter.

Comment: A member function using other members of the same class is totally normal, and really doesn't need any special emphasis. It would be much better to make use of non-members stand out, because that's where you might have to be more careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Don't Repeat Yourself

In software development, there is a general principle called ["Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
It's best to avoid repeating information because:

1. If you update the information (such as the name of the class), you will have to make that change in multiple places.
2. The repeated information doesn't serve any purpose. It's just noise which makes it harder for the reader to comprehend the code, because there is more to read.

```cpp
void ClassOne::methodTwo() {
   methodOne();
}
```

In this example, it is possible to write `ClassOne::methodOne()` or even `::ClassOne::methodOne()`, but it would be totally pointless. This code is located in a member function of `ClassOne`, so we already know that `methodOne()` is *possibly* a member function.
If you want to be *certain* that it is a member function, there are better ways to express that.

#### Alternative Ways of Explicitly Referring to Members

If you want to emphasize that it is a member function, you can:

- add a prefix to your member functions, e.g. `m_methodOne()`
- use `this` when accessing members, i.e. `this->methodOne()`

These two methods don't repeat the class name, but still emphasize that we are using a member function, making them much better.

#### Sometimes, You Must Repeat the Class Name

Note that sometimes, you are left with no other choice than to repeat the class name, in order to disambiguate.
For example, if you inherit from to classes `A` and `B` which both have a member function called `method()`, you will have to write `A::method()` or `B::method()` to disambiguate and choose the right one.

However, situations like that are *very uncommon*.
Using the class name *only* in these cases has the added benefit that we're emphasizing them and making it obvious that something unusual is taking place.